# Sending mail is not working on my site

Tags: asp.net, ajax, handler

I have a site online, its not finished..

my problem is at the bottom "contact-us" forum.
its not sending any mail..

*in my local host it is working and i have no idea what is the different

java script code for sending the mail:

```
  function sendEmail_click() {
                if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                    // $("#LoadingImage").show(); //Show loading image
                    var settings = {
                        'data': getData(),
                        'url': "Handlers/SendMail.ashx",
                        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    };
                    sendEmail(settings);
                };
            }

            function getData() {
                var data = {
                    'firstName': $('#txt_fName').val(),
                    'lastName': $('#txt_lName').val(),
                    'phone': $('#txt_phone').val(),
                    'bName': $('#txt_bName').val(),
                    'fromMail': $('#txt_email').val(),
                    'Message': $('#txt_message').val(),
                    'checkBox': $('#chk_ad').prop('checked')
                };
                return data;
            }

            function showOrHideLoadingImage(id, action) {
                if (action == "show") {
                    $("#" + id).show();
                } else {
                    $("#" + id).hide();
                }
            }

            function sendEmail(settings) {
                var success = false;

                showOrHideLoadingImage("LoadingImage", "show");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: settings.contentType,
                    data: settings.data,
                    url: settings.url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#checkMark').css('display', 'inline').fadeOut(20000); //Show check mark image+text
                        $(".contact_input").each(function () {
                            $(this).val("");
                        })

                        success = true;
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $('#xMark').css('display', 'inline').fadeOut(12000); //Show xMark image+text
                        success = false;
                    }
                }).always(function () {
                    showOrHideLoadingImage("LoadingImage", "hide");
                });
                return success;
            }
```

Handler:

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    //add try catch
    // Loads parameters into variables
    string firstName = context.Request.Form.Get("firstName");
    string lastName = context.Request.Form.Get("lastName");
    string phone = context.Request.Form.Get("phone");
    string bName = context.Request.Form.Get("bName");
    string senderEmail = context.Request.Form.Get("fromMail");
    string message = context.Request.Form.Get("message");
    string chkBox_ad = context.Request.Form.Get("checkBox");

    bool mailSent = Mail.SendEmail(firstName, lastName, bName, phone, senderEmail, message, chkBox_ad);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    if (mailSent)
    {
        context.Response.Write("true");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Write("false");

    }
}
```

Send mail function:

```
 public static bool SendEmail(string firstName, string lastName, string bName, string phone, string senderEmail, string message, string chkBox_ad)
{
    chkBox_ad = chkBox_ad == "true" ? "..." : "...";
    //  Email sending
    string eBody = "...";
    eBody += "...";
    eBody += "...";
    eBody += "...";
    eBody += "...";
    eBody += "...";


    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("XXX@gmail.com", "XXX@gmail.com", "smbJob", eBody);
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone having that issue, I managed to solve it:

1) this is the right web.config setting(replace "info@yourDomainName.com" with your "goDaddy" email address

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="info@yourDomainName.com">
      <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

As I understand, "goDaddy" dont allow sending mails from third-party accounts, like gmail(after live chatting with them), dont have to write user name & passowrd and its not through SSL.

your from address should be your "goDaddy" email address

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the exact code you need but it should get you going in the correct direction. Make sure you are using the correct using directive as well.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = 
        new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("xxx@gmail.com",  "xxx@gmail.com");

try
{
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
   {
      UserName = "someemail@address.com",
      Password = "password"
   };
   client.EnableSsl = true;
 }
 catch
 {
    display some error from here
 }
```

Comment: The email sending working on loclHost, the problem began when i uploaded the site to "goDaddy" hosting.